# how constructor in applet work and how event is handled?

Tags: java, applet

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;

/*
 <applet code="XOR" width=400 height=200>
 </applet>
 */
public class XOR extends Applet {
   int chsX = 100, chsY = 100;

   public XOR() {
      addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
         public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
            int x = me.getX();
            int y = me.getY();
            chsX = x - 10;
            chsY = y - 10;
            repaint();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

In above program when applet is started then obviously XOR() is called.AddMouseMotionListener() takes argument of a listener refernce.But here wat is happening.Here in parameter first an object of MouseMotionAdapter is made and some statements are written .How these can act as a refernce to listener for addMouseMotionListener().Please clearify my doubt ?? I am not able to understand anything here.

Comment: Normally what you think what is placed inside addmouseMotionListener(?) what is placed at '?' location?

Comment: Your code is without any indentations making it all left justified and thus more difficult to read, understand and debug. Please re-format your posted code by giving it proper indentations, usually 4 spaces per block, and making sure that all code on the same block is on the same indentation level. Your cooperation in this would be greatly appreciated and will likely improve your chances of getting a decent and prompt answer.

Comment: in place of ? a reference to a listener is written .means who will respond to the event genereted by source.